# Create table error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

Any ideas why I can not create CLinical_QUestions table?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Questions` (
`QuestionID` INT NOT NULL ,
`Question` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
`VersionNumber` INT NULL ,
`Core` TINYINT(1) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`QuestionID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I can not create this table

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Clinical_Questions` (
`ClinicalID` INT NOT NULL ,
`QuestionID` INT NULL ,
`Effective Week` INT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ClinicalID`) ,
INDEX `QuestionID_idx` (`QuestionID` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `QuestionID`
FOREIGN KEY (`QuestionID` )
REFERENCES `test`.`Questions` (`QuestionID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `ClinicalID`
FOREIGN KEY (`ClinicalID` )
REFERENCES `test`.`Clinical` (`ClinicalID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'certestdb.Clinical_Questions' (errno: 121)

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Overall_Week_Rating` (
`ClinicalID` INT NOT NULL ,
`Instructor_Rating` INT NULL ,
`DateTime_Instructor_Rating` DATETIME NULL ,
`Student_Rating` INT NULL ,
`DateTime_Student_Rating` DATETIME NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ClinicalID`) ,
CONSTRAINT `UserID`
FOREIGN KEY (`ClinicalID` )
REFERENCES `test`.`Clinical` (`ClinicalID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Does your MySQL user allow you to create tables? What if you remove the schema name `certestdb`, can you create it then?

Comment: Yes I've created 8 tables already

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your `CREATE TABLE` statement somewhere on the declaration if `INDEX`. You should remove `ASC` from the index part.

```
INDEX `Section_idx` (`Question_Section`)
```

The second problem that will arise is that you have no key define on the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint,

```
CONSTRAINT cons_EffectiveDate
    FOREIGN KEY (`Effective Date`)                -- add column name
    REFERENCES `certestdb`.`Section` (columnHere) -- add also column name
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Comment: What is the full eror message?

Comment: where is table `certestdb.Overall_Week_Rating`?

Comment: can you add the structure for `Overall_Week_Rating`?